# Задача по системному программированию. (Массивы) [C++]

Tags: c++, массивы, многопоточность

Задача:

> "Дан массив размером более 5000 элементов. Первый поток заполняет его случайными числами, второй поток - секундомер. Найти время заполнения массива."

Не знаю как сделать секундомер и подсчитать время заполнения...
Прошу помощи, желательно с комментариями и пояснениями.

Comment: Первый поток блокирует какой нибудь мутекс и пишет себе спокойно массив. А второй получает текущее время и спит на этом мутексе, когда проснется получает текущее время и вычисляет разницу

Comment: Задание есть - делайте. В чём именно вопрос? Как сделать секундомер или как заполнять случайными числами?

Comment: @Mike, непонятно, как первый поток узнает, что ему пора начинать ожидание.

Comment: @gbg тогда нужен второй мутекс блокирующийся до запуска потоков и разблокирующийся первым потоком при начале работы. правда надо еще как то убедится что второй поток на этот момент уже работает. думаю третьим мутексом можно решить :) Хотя боюсь препод под словом "секундомер" понимал какой то постоянно работающий цикл

Comment: @Mike задачу дал препод по системному программированию, а так как я отсутствовал первый семестр - я вообще полный ноль в этом, даже малейшего представления не имею. А сроки поджимают на столько, что изучать это по книгам и документациям не вариант, вот и прошу помощи у людей знающих в этом толк. Что такое Мутексы и с каким гарниром их употребляют - я не шарю к сожалению. Есть задача - от меня требуется решение... Вот такое болото!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень странная задача, я бы например показал что-то такое:

```
echo '
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10000000
int a[N];
int main(){
  for (int i=0; i < N;i++)
    a[i] = rand();
  printf("%d", a[ rand() % N]);
  return 0;
}' | gcc -x c - -o 5 && time ./5
```

Comment: Читер! :) .....

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я думаю такое сдать сумел бы) формально все условия соблюдены.

Comment: Посмотрю как это работает @pavel, очень надеюсь, что ваш вариант - это именно то, что мне нужно! Благодарю, как будет результат хоть какой то - отпишусь!

Comment: @pavel что значит строка _| gcc -x c - -o 5 && time ./5_ ?

Comment: С чем несогласны минусующие? Скомпилированный код будет выполняться в одном потоке/процессе, замер времени - в другом.